# How can I implement a method to print an object in the super class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

When I run this, I get the desired string corresponding to the species object that is created. My goal here is to be able to create a method called speak in the Animal class that achieves the same thing. But I don't have a good understanding on how to do that.

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def speak():
        pass

class Mammal(Animal):

    def __init__(self):
        Animal.__init__(self)

class Cat(Mammal):

    def __init__(self):
        Mammal.__init__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "meeeow"

class Dog(Mammal):

    def __init__(self):
        Mammal.__init__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "wooof"

class Primate(Mammal):

    def __init__(self):
        Mammal.__init__(self)

class Hacker(Primate):

    def __init__(self):
        Primate.__init__(self)

    def __str__(self):
        return "Hello world!"

garfield = Cat()
print(garfield)

spike = Dog()
print(spike)

john = Hacker()
print(john)
```

Comment: What is the problem with creating a method with another name but same code?

Comment: The name of the method could be anything, I just need to be able to call cat_name.speak() and and it return the string associated with that subclass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yours inherited classes can access any method defined in the parent class. So to achieve this, just define a new method called `speak` in `Animal` class and `print` as you did in your examples:

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self):
        print(self)
        pass

    def speak(self):
        print(self)
```

Then just create the instance and call the function:

```
garfield = Cat()
garfield.speak()
```

**Output**

```
meeeow
```

Comment: Okay, I see now. This makes a lot more sense. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Modify your Animal class like below. When you call the super method from your subclass, you're passing the instance of the class you created to the parent's init function. So the instance of class is passed to the Mammal init function, which calls super and passes the instance to the Animal init function.

```
class Animal(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.speak()

    def speak(self):
        print(self)
```